# How to get the position of first TRUE in any row or column of dataframe in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this tibble/dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
  b = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
  c = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  a     b     c    
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
3 FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
4 TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

by first TRUE I mean:

positions:

[image]

distances:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1     2
2     1     2     3
3     2     3     4
4     3     4     5
```

The distance from `c(2, 2)` to `c(1,1)` is two steps (one left and one up) (distance = 2), so every cell has a distance from `c(1, 1)`. The first TRUE with the minimum distance is the first TRUE, so the desired output in this example is `c(2,2)`; when you have two or more cells first TRUE with equal distance, you put them in a list as a result like this `list(c(1, 2), c(4, 3))`. I figured this is called manhattan distance.

Comment: Do you mean the desired output would be `list(c(2, 3), c(3, 2))` for the second case. Shouldn't the first `TRUE` position always be only 1 position ? What is the logic of returning `c(2, 3)` and `c(3, 2)` ?

Comment: They are at the same distance from `c(1,1)`

Comment: In the first case `c(2,2)` is the nearest from `c(1,1)`

Comment: How do you calculate the distance ? How do you know which one is nearest?

Comment: But c(1, 3) is the "first TRUE in any row or column" for row 1 and for column 3; c(2, 2) is the first TRUE for row 2 and column 2; and c(3, 1) is the first TRUE for row 3 and column.

Comment: Or do you mean closest to c(1, 1) as in minimum distance:`sqrt((row(df) - 1)^2 + (col(df) - 1)^2)`.

Comment: My bad I didn't explain myself in a better way, I updated the post. Yes @dcarlson

Comment: BUT c(3, 1 ) is also 2 steps, just 2 steps horizontally. However is is only 1.4 units whereas c(3, 1) is 2 units.

Comment: `c(3, 1)` is `FALSE`, so it does not count.

Comment: The confusion here is whether you are wanting ONLY the distance from c(1,1) to the nearest TRUE or whether you are wanting an algorithm that determines the distance from any position to the nearest TRUE.

Comment: Also, generally this site isn't designed to come up with algorithms for you. There are other sites to do that. See the help on what qualifies as a good question for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
dst <- (row(df) - 1) + (col(df) - 1)
dst[as.matrix(!df)] <- NA
which(dst==min(dst, na.rm=TRUE), arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   2   2
```

The results will be a matrix with 1 or more rows. You can convert that to a list if necessary.